# Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741819 (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've run into this problem for my Android application, I'm trying to create an action bar down at the bottom of my application involving three different menus but I have aadt crashing on me. The error message I have turns up as this and aapt crashes.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.authport.Auth" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_charge"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_charge"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_history"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_setup"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Now is this a simple fix that I am missing or is there a larger problem that needs to be addressed? Any help would benefit me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your posting...

It's because one of your @string is not defined

I have same return code as yours